`maven-failsafe-plugin` suddenly stopped generating summary file starting with `3.3.0` to `3.4.0` update
maven-failsafe-plugin suddenly stopped generating summary file starting with 3.3.0 to 3.4.0 update. This is causing a failure because of which mvn clean verify won't succeed on my java project.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.5.0:verify (integration-test-verify) on project ABC: /Users/rohan.zaveri/abc/def/xyz/target/failsafe-reports/failsafe-summary-abc.xml (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]

My maven-failsafe-plugin setup for integration test reports and verification in the pom.xml file of my java project root module:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups>true</log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups>
            <log4j2.configurationFile>log4j2.properties</log4j2.configurationFile>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test-abc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-XX:+StartAttachListener ${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                <summaryFile>target/failsafe-reports/failsafe-summary-abc.xml</summaryFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test-verify</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <summaryFiles>
                    <summaryFile>target/failsafe-reports/failsafe-summary-abc.xml</summaryFile>
                </summaryFiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

When I try to update the version from 3.3.0 to 3.4.0 or 3.5.0, and execute mvn clean verify, the verify execution goal on maven-failsafe-plugin suddenly fails because it can't find the summary file target/failsafe-reports/failsafe-summary-abc.xml. On further investigation, I found that the summary file is not generated by the integration-test execution goal itself.
The only change is the version update. With 3.3.0, the summary file is generated and with 3.4.0 or 3.5.0, the file ceases to be generated.
The first module in my project to fail has no integration tests, but that has always been the case. With 3.3.0, the integration-test goal will still generate the summary file with the result 254 like so -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<failsafe-summary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/failsafe-summary.xsd" result="254" timeout="false">
    <completed>0</completed>
    <errors>0</errors>
    <failures>0</failures>
    <skipped>0</skipped>
    <failureMessage xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</failsafe-summary>

indicating that the module not having integration test shouldn't be the root cause.
Other than that, I tried to see some new parameters introduced by maven-failsafe-plugin:3.4.0 but didn't find anything that could explain this issue.
I can see the goals executing in the logs:
[INFO] --- failsafe:3.5.0:integration-test (integration-test-abc) @ ABC ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- failsafe:3.5.0:verify (integration-test-verify) @ ABC ---
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.5.0:verify (integration-test-verify) on project ABC: /Users/rohan.zaveri/abc/def/xyz/target/failsafe-reports/failsafe-summary-abc.xml (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]


I was not able to find a similar issue posted by anyone on any online forums. Can anyone help? I am trying to figure out what has changed from maven-failsafe-plugin:3.3.0 to maven-failsafe-plugin:3.4.0 that is causing this failure.

Are you sure that integration-test goal is even running? Do you see it in logs?

Yes, I see it in the logs. Updated post with the logs.

I'm unable to reproduce this problem. Looks like something else is interfering.

Looks like you need to add method breakpoint for writeSummary in org.apache.maven.plugin.failsafe.util.FailsafeSummaryXmlUtils and go to wonderful journey of debugging maven pluggins :)

Why are you configuring the summaryFile in both goals at all? Second the output shown tells me that there have no integration tests being executed that means there is no report generated... Also I'm using new versions of plugin (3.5.0) and the file is generated  (https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/tree/main/episode-2)

This is a subset of configuration I am showing from my pom.xml file. I have multiple integration-test executions setup with different system properties. That is why I override the default summary file path.
Secondly, Yes the module has no tests. But I have mentioned how version 3.3.0 still generated a summary for it with a result code 254 but version 3.4.0 doesn't. Example summary file generated by 3.3.0 version of the plugin is provided in the post.
